# Send javascript array to php array after loading and redirect user

Tags: javascript, html, random, timer, digits

I would like to redirect a user to a php page containing a form field after the user has viewed the three numbers after each other. I would like to also pass the index array to a php array for processing and storage.

Here's the code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">

    <title>Digit Span Backward</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Digit Span Backward - Javascript edition</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function randomize(number)
        {
            var index = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                index.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
            }

            return index;
        }

        function showMessage(message)
        {
            $('p').html(message);
        }   

        var i = 0;

        function shuffle(list, i)
        {
            if (!(i >= 0)) 
            {
                i = 0;
            }

            setTimeout((function(msg)
            {
                i++;
                return function()
                {
                    if(i < list.length)
                    {
                        shuffle(list, i);
                    }

                    showMessage(msg);
                }
            })(list[i]), 1000);
        }

    </script>

    <form>
        <input type="button" onclick="shuffle(randomize(3))" value="Start Digit Span Backward">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i am not a HTML 5 geek or a php professional but here is my suggestion

Can i suggest putting a hidden field in the page and then use the join method of the array to convert it to string splitted by what ever choice splitter like , and then set it to the hidden field value and pass it to the next page just give it a name

Example 
JavaScript Function

```
function ArrayToStringSplitted(ary,splitter,hiddenfield)
{
    var aryString= ary.join(spliter);
    hiddenfield.value = aryString ; 
}
```

HTML
just add the Hidden Field to the page

```
<input type='hidden' id="hdfld" name="hdfld" />
```

i think this will not work with the normal javascript redirection window.location = path 
i think this will work with setting the form attributes the action to the location of the php page and the method to post

in there in the php page you can catch the hiddenfield value with $hiddenfield name and split it with the same splitter to return it to a array again

regards

Comment: Thank you, but I am not sure how you transfer the list with the numbers after they have loaded.

Comment: it transfer to the php page with the post action of the form with in the hidden field variable is that what u mean ?>

Comment: like the example the if i got a array of numbers 
var a = [1,2,3]; just use join function to make it a string splitted 
a.join(','); that will make it 1,2,3 string , put it in the hidden field it will be passed with posted form